# What is "too large" for a SkSL shader, and how can I use larger shaders?

Tags: shader, compose-desktop, compose-multiplatform

I can get Compose to render a fragment shader:

```kotlin
fun main() = singleWindowApplication(title = "Shaaaderrrs") {
    val runtimeEffect = remember {
        RuntimeEffect.makeForShader(
            """
                uniform vec3 iResolution;
                vec4 main(in vec2 fragCoord) {
                    return vec4(fragCoord / iResolution.xy, 0, 1); 
                }
            """.trimIndent()
        )
    }

    val shader by derivedStateOf {
        val builder = RuntimeShaderBuilder(runtimeEffect)
        builder.uniform("iResolution", 800.0f, 600.0f, 1.0f)
        builder.makeShader()
    }

    val brush by derivedStateOf {
        ShaderBrush(shader)
    }

    Surface(modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colors.surface)) {
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            drawRect(brush = brush, size = Size(800.0f, 600.0f))
        }
    }
}
```

From here, I'm trying to get some real pieces from ShaderToy to work.

Skia's shader language is SkSL, but it's similar enough to GLSL that many ShaderToy shaders work with very little modification.

Sometimes I am greeted by this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: error: program is too large
1 error
    at org.jetbrains.skia.RuntimeEffectKt._nMakeForShader(Native Method)
    at org.jetbrains.skia.RuntimeEffectKt.access$_nMakeForShader(RuntimeEffect.kt:1)
    at org.jetbrains.skia.RuntimeEffect$Companion.makeForShader(RuntimeEffect.kt:11)
    at com.example.common.ShaderToyKt.ShaderToy(ShaderToy.kt:46)
    at com.example.common.AppKt.App(App.kt:8)
```

This happens particularly often for raymarching shaders which tend to contain large loops. This is a pain for me, as I was particularly interested in using this to run raymarching demos.

So, how do I get this limit increased? The shader I'm trying works fine with GLSL in the browser, so I think it's completely reasonable to expect it to work here.

Additional:

- [Demo Repository](https://github.com/hakanai/ComposeShaderDemo)

Comment: +1, i got same problem using nesting loop. `for(int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {for(int j = -1; j <= 1; j++){} }` , maybe its need to precompile into SPIR-V byte. any update on this?

Comment: @SayyidJ Yeah the update was I added the demo repository so people could see it happening for themselves more easily. Also added the bounty at the same time because this is one of the major blockers for an app I'd love to try making.